# Group by date and count values in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sorting, group-by, count

I have the following pandas dataframe (I am using python):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
'date': ['2020-07-01', '2020-07-01', '2020-07-01', '2020-07-01', '2020-07-02', '2020-07-02', '2020-07-02'],
'value': ['abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'bb', 'bb', 'bb', 'c']})

df.head(7)

    date    value
0   2020-07-01  abc
1   2020-07-01  abc
2   2020-07-01  abc
3   2020-07-01  bb
4   2020-07-02  bb
5   2020-07-02  bb
6   2020-07-02  c
```

How can I get this:

```
    date    value  count
0   2020-07-01  abc  3
1   2020-07-01  bb   1
2   2020-07-02  bb   2
3   2020-07-02  c    1
```

or this:

```
    date    value  count
0   2020-07-01  abc  3
                bb   1
1   2020-07-02  bb   2
                c    1
```

Both solutions work equally fine for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
df2 = df.groupby(by = ['date','value'])['value'].count().to_frame(name='count')
```

result:

```
                  count
date       value       
2020-07-01 abc        3
           bb         1
2020-07-02 bb         2
           c          1
```

or:

```
df2 = df.groupby(by = ['date','value'])['value'].count().to_frame(name='count').reset_index()
```

which gives:

```
         date value  count
0  2020-07-01   abc      3
1  2020-07-01    bb      1
2  2020-07-02    bb      2
3  2020-07-02     c      1
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do `value_counts`

```
s=df.groupby('date').value.value_counts().to_frame('count')
                  count
date       value       
2020-07-01 abc        3
           bb         1
2020-07-02 bb         2
           c          1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `value_counts` in an `.agg()` function

```
df.groupby('date').agg(count=('value', 'value_counts')).reset_index()



     date value  count
0  2020-07-01   abc      3
1  2020-07-01    bb      1
2  2020-07-02    bb      2
3  2020-07-02     c      1
```